# Entity Resolution

Tags: database, entity, resolution, scientific-computing

I ask this question to people in the field of scientific research: I want to know the difference between the two terms "Entity Resolution" and'' Entity matching "in the context of databases.
or if it means the same thing?

Answer (score 1):

Entity resolution, entity matching, record linkage, duplicate detection, relational clustering, coreference resolution, reference reconciliation, database hardening, entity disambiguation, merge/purge or record matching describe quite similar research problems: the process of identifying groups of records that refer to the same real-world entity. Different research and application areas favour different terms.

However, as far as I can decide, there is a slight difference between resolution and matching.  Entity matching is usually used to describe matching of record/entity pairs, deciding if they refer to the same thing only looking at the given pair. Entity resolution, on the other hand, describes the process of deducing all matchings; eg. if we know that records r1 matches r2 and r2 matches r3, then the whole entity contains r1, r2, r3, including r1 matching r3.

In the context of databases, entity matching is closer to similarity joins between records, while entity resolution is closer to an iterative process of repeated similarity joins.